# default_scope in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, default-scope

I know named_scope has been changed to scope in rails 3.

How do I perform default_scope in rails 3, I've had a good google but found nothing for defaults scopes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

default_scope is available in Rails 3.0, see the following

- [Lighthouse Ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3838-with_exclusive_scope-does-not-override-the-default_scope-when-each-provides-is-null-is-not-null-conditions) referencing default_scope in Rails 3.0
- [Github](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c6372d604952a8eef16ce73a06814aa143b94779/activerecord/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb) Rails 3.0 scope code
- [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/112-anonymous-scopes) about scope in Rails 3.0

Comment: Is default_scope going to remain in rails3? It won't be deprecated in coming versions?

Comment: I use default_scope in a number of of Rails3 apps and I haven't seen a deprecation warning, so I assume it will remain.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another pointer: the api doc for [AR::Base.default_scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-default_scope)

Comment: in rails 3.2 this is the method http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope

Answer (score 0):

`default_scope where(:abc => val)`